# upload file to FTP from Blackberry application

Tags: blackberry, ftp

I am newbie to Blackberry application development. Can anyone have idea how to upload files to FTP from blackberry application ?

Answer (score 1):

1. use SocketConnection and send ftp commands.
2. use any 3rd party api like [simpleFTP](http://www.jibble.org/simpleftp/)

Comment: can you please give me some sample tutorial for SocketConnection?

Comment: @Jim if u have got solution,then please help me or give here answer so that i can also review it.